# サイトの PHP ファイルをアップロードする場所はどこですか？

Tags: php

サイトのファイルをアップロードする際 PHPファイル は HTML CSS 等 とおなじところにあげればいいのでしょうか？

自デバイスでは PHP実行不可なので

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アップロード先のルール次第です。例えばレンタルサーバを利用している場合には、「任意のディレクトリに置けば良い」または「`cgi-bin`以下に配置する必要がある」など、なんらかの決まりごとがマニュアル等に記載されているはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます また … それは別質問を立てたいとおもいます